# color and overlap issues with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Here is my html

```
<canvas class="row" id="myCanvas" width="500" height="50" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"  ></canvas>
```

and this is javascript

```
function showProgress() {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.fillText("welcome", c.width/2, c.height/2);
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.font = "30px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 270, 75);
    }
    showProgress();
```

I have following two issues.
1. Green fill rectangle is hiding the text. How can I show that text on top of fill color.
2. I would like text (welcome in this case) color to be red. Is there anyway of modifying just the text color.

code could be found at jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Lp24q01s/

Comment: Have fillText() after fillRect()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function showProgress() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 270, 75);

  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillText("welcome", c.width/2, c.height/2);
}
showProgress();
```

The canvas context uses the entire state to draw things and they're drawn in the order you call them. Want the text on top of a rectangle? Draw the rectangle first. Want to change the color? Set color to green, draw rectangle, set color to red, draw text.

It doesn't have a native way to say "the rectangle is green." It's more "the next thing you draw will have a fill style of green, I think I'll draw a rectangle" so you have a green rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showProgress() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 270, 75);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";// red text
  ctx.fillText("welcome", c.width/2, c.height/2);
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
}
showProgress();
```

you should put the `fillText` after the `fillRect`, also you need to set the  `fillStyle`
because canvas is just a `Finite State Machine`, it can't remember what you was done.
if you make some difference state(such as change the fillStyle), and do another render(such as fillRect), the current result will always cover the result you done before.